# Android wheelchairs

Tags: voice-recognition, accessibility, voice-command, google-voice, voice

I was wondering whether there exist any Android wheelchairs that run Android.

These could allow people that were unable to move their limbs but could still use voice to control their wheelchair through voice by talking into a phone in the front part of the wheelchair connected to the wheelchair via Bluetooth.

Currently, Android has something known as [voice access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess) to control your phone via voice.

But it could be nice, if, this mechanism could be extended to connect to a wheelchair via Bluetooth and control it via voice.

Perhaps the phone can also be powered on and off via a voice command.

Not sure about the charging part, but I think a robotic part that could find the wall socket and charge wheelchair and phone simultaneously would be nice.

This would be very useful to people with no arms and legs or to people whose arms and legs were paralyzed such as paraplegic or tetraplegic people, but who could still use their voice to connect to their phone, operate their wheelchair, move about and communicate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps towards this exist. Examples include:

- [Smart wheelchair prototype based on Android](https://eudl.eu/pdf/10.4108/eai.23-11-2019.2298338)
- [Smart wheelchair using android smartphone for physically disabled people](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325280795_Smart_wheelchair_using_android_smartphone_for_physically_disabled_people)

A web search will find plenty more.